# JSON on Node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, loops, undefined

i'm new to Node, and i want to parse a JSON from an API.

The thing is that i can access to almost all of the JSON, but it has some elements i'm not getting.

```
var request = require("request");

var url = 'https://cf.biwenger.com/api/v1/competitions/la-liga/data';
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(body);

        console.log(jsonObject.data.teams);
    }
});
```

I have this code to obtain the teams on the JSON, and that is what i obtain:

```
{ '1': 
  { id: 1,
    name: 'Athletic',
    slug: 'athletic',
    nextMatch: 
     { id: 4665,
       date: 1522505700,
       round: [Object],
       home: true,
       against: [Object] } },
 '2': 
  { id: 2,
    name: 'Atlético',
    slug: 'atletico',
    nextMatch: 
     { id: 4668,
       date: 1522608300,
       round: [Object],
       home: true,
       against: [Object] } },
 '3': 
  { id: 3,
    name: 'Barcelona',
    slug: 'barcelona',
    nextMatch: 
     { id: 4666,
       date: 1522521900,
       round: [Object],
       home: false,
       against: [Object] } },
 ...(and much more)
```

Now i want to obtain all the names of the teams, i tried to do it, but i always got undefined, unless i put something like:

```
console.log(jsonObject.data.teams["1"]["name"]); //Athletic
console.log(jsonObject.data.teams["2"]["name"]); //Atlético
```

How can i iterate through that JSON without getting undefined??

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get an array by using `Object.values` and then map over it

```js
const data = { 
  '1': { 
    id: 1,
    name: 'Athletic',
    slug: 'athletic'
  },
  '2': {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Man Utd',
    slug: 'man-utd'
  },
  '3': {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Liverpool',
    slug: 'liverpool'
  }
};

const getTeams = data => 
  Object.values(data)
    .map(team => team.name);
    
console.log(getTeams(data));
```

You can read about `Object.values` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), and the `Array.prototype.map` function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

Get the values using the function `Object.values` and loop over that array using a `for-loop`:

```
Object.values(jsonObject.data.teams).forEach(function(team) {
    console.log(team.name)
})
```

```js
var jsonObject = {  data: {    teams: {      '1': {        id: 1,        name: 'Athletic',        slug: 'athletic',        nextMatch: {          id: 4665,          date: 1522505700,          round: [Object],          home: true,          against: [Object]        }      },      '2': {        id: 2,        name: 'Atlético',        slug: 'atletico',        nextMatch: {          id: 4668,          date: 1522608300,          round: [Object],          home: true,          against: [Object]        }      },      '3': {        id: 3,        name: 'Barcelona',        slug: 'barcelona',        nextMatch: {          id: 4666,          date: 1522521900,          round: [Object],          home: false,          against: [Object]        }      }    }  }}

Object.values(jsonObject.data.teams).forEach(function(team) {
    console.log(team.name);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to iterate through the names of each team in the most straightforward sense, you can iterate over each team, then access the name of each team:

```
for (var id in jsonObject.teams) {
  if (jsonObject.teams.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
    console.log(jsonObject.teams[id].name);
  }
}
```

I am not sure what you mean when you say you're "getting undefined," though. Could you please show us the way you're attempting to do it so we can understand the error in your understanding?